# Regex to find more than 2 curly braces inside double quotes text

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to find all strings having more than 2 curly braces blocks ie.,
 2 dynamic values like {{data1}} {{data2}} between double quotes

Ex:

```
class="xyz level1 {{disabled}} what is the {{contentStyle}} result"
```

I tried but no luck

(.*?{{){1,}

Comment: something like this `\{\{[^{}]+\}\}` ?

Comment: 2 curly braces or 2 blocks in curly braces? 2 or more than 2?

Comment: More than 2 blocks. Sorry I will update question

Comment: I don't think I understand even after the edit. Could you share the text from the input string that you actually want to match? E.g. do you want `disabled` and `contentStyle` or something else?

Comment: Yes disabled and contentStyle in my example.result these 2 or if there are more blocks result all related blocks.

Comment: @Kurkula is inside double quotes a required condition??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `\{\{(\w+)?\}\}`? This will match the text inside mustache style curly braces.

[regexer](http://regexr.com/3gh2j)

Comment: this looks for even one value. I am trying for >1 value between double quotes

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for a test of two matches - try String.protoype.match and testing against length

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

```
function x(str) {
    return str.match(/\{\{(\w+)?\}\}/g).length > 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually meant two or more curly braces, you could use the following:

`(({){2,})\S*((}){2,})/g`

Note, that if you actually want 3 or more curly braces (more than 2, ex {{{code}}}), you can just change the 2s in the example above to 3.

This works by capturing a first group `(({){2,})`, where `({)` matches the open curly bracket, and the `{2,}` captures two or more of the preceding group. It then allows any number of (the `*`) non-white-space (the `\S`) characters, and stops matching when it encounters `((}){2,})`, which is the same as what I described for the opening sequence, only with a `}` instead. The `\g` is the global flag, allowing it to match multiple instances of the pattern, not just the first.

Comment: this is a bad pattern and illegal repetation.

Comment: It's illegal repetition in Java, not in JavaScript. Given that the user posted what looks like an html attribute (class) and that his post is litteraly tagged with 'JavaScript' your comment should be qualified with, 'this is an illegal repetition in an irrelevant language to the question asked'

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern `(\{\{[^}]+\}\})(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tgokeq/5)

it will catch inside double quotes only as per title.

Comment: this searches even for 1 value. I am trying for >1 value.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit hairy but you can do this with the following regex:

```
let pattern = /([^{}]*\{\{[^{}]+\}\}[^{}]*){2,}/
```

A few examples:

```
pattern.test('') // false
pattern.test('{{a}}{{b}}') // true
pattern.test('{{a}}{{fdsa}fdsa}{{4{{3fdsafds42}}fdsafds') // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of your match, this will give you the information about how many 2 curly braces blocks are there:

```
var p = /(\{\{.+?\}\})/g;
var str = "xyz level1 {{disabled}} what is the {{contentStyle}} result {{what}} is the";
var res = str.match(p); /* here res will either null or an array */
if(res && res.length > 2){
    console.log("yes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that assumes your braces are always correctly paired:

```
\w*(?=(\}){2,})
```